# Check if object is defined after initialization in c#

Tags: c#, .net, object, if-statement, syntax

I have the following object (class).

```
namespace Temp.Models
{
    public class CurrentClass
    {
        private double _firstCoefficient;
        private double _secondCoefficient;

        public double FirstCoefficient
        {
            get { return _firstCoefficient; }
            set { _firstCoefficient= value; }
        }
        public double SecondCoefficient
        {
            get { return _secondCoefficient; }
            set { _secondCoefficient= value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The following class utilizes the above object and therefore initializes the object as follows:

```
namespace Temp.Models
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        private CurrentClass _currentClass = new CurrentClass();

        public CurrentClass CurrentClass
        {
            get { return _currentClass; }
            set { _currentClass = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

At some point if certain conditions are met I would define the variables as follows:

```
MainClass currentObject = new MainClass();
//if conditions are met
currentObject.CurrentClass.FirstCoefficient = 0;
currentObject.CurrentClass.SecondCoefficient = 5;
```

But what if the conditions are never met and I never define the above variables. How and/or what is the best way to check if the object was never defined?

I can do the following check:

```
if(currentObject.CurrentClass.FirstCoefficient != 0 && currentObject.CurrentClass.SecondCoefficent != 0)
```

But the values can be defined as 0...So I am not sure how to go about this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Consider using the type "double?" rather than "double" then you can check for null

Comment: I assume there is a reason why you don't just do the same check on the conditions instead of checking the `CurrentClass` instance?

Comment: @ScottPerham I see what you mean, this would be reasonable solution for this object, but I actually have other objects with multiple different types in them. Include enums and so and...so what would you do in this scenario?

Comment: The best idea would be to avoid this problem completely using immutable classes (parametrize through constructor, make all fields/properties read-only). Therefore any existing object must be in a valid state. If you cannot do that, use `Nullable<T>` but prepare for a lot of needless consistency checks everywhere.

Comment: @Crowcoder how would I check the instance itself? I tried setting CurrentClass != null but it thinks the object is truly not null even if not defined (just when it is initialized)...

Comment: I would think your check would be "if conditions NOT met then object NOT initialized" since that is the only way you would set values on the object.

Comment: @Crowcoder I see thanks for the information. I believe that could be one solution...tbh there are so many provided solutions now, I am not sure what would be the best approach?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek I'll have to look into immutable classes. Do you by any chance have a simple example or a good source? Thanks!

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek I believe with the way the code is structured using Nullable types may be the best solution for my approach if you wanted to submit that as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some principles that can be used for solving the problem with description, samples and brief evaluation/opinion.

### 1. Parametrization through constructors

According to OOP principles, a constructor is method used to initialize an object to a valid state. The concept of immutability takes this even further, disallowing any changes, completely avoiding invalid state.

There is also a possibility of compromise where the API of an object disallows invalid states.

With this concept, you would arrive to:

```
namespace Temp.Models
{
    public class CurrentClass
    {
        public double FirstCoefficient { get; private set; }
        public double SecondCoefficient { get; private set; }

        public CurrentClass(double firstCoefficient, double secondCoefficient)
        {
            FirstCoefficient = firstCoefficient;
            SecondCoefficient = secondCoefficient;
        }

        // if mutability is required - this is needless as the constructor is
        // the same but if there was more complex state, methods like this would make
        // sense, mutating only parts of the state
        public void SetCoefficients(double firstCoefficient, double secondCoefficient)
        {
            FirstCoefficient = firstCoefficient;
            SecondCoefficient = secondCoefficient;
        }
    }
}
```

Summary:

- Each instantiation of `CurrentClass` is always in a valid state, avoiding a lot of consistency checks (improved encapsulation)
- It takes more code to write (but you save a lot of other code due to the previous point)
- You need to know the coefficients beforehand.

### 2. Using nullable types

Nullable types add the "additional" value to types, the "undefined" state. Reference types (`class`) are nullable by design while value types (`struct`) need to be marked nullable, either as `Nullable<T>` or with the shorthand `T?`.

This then allows the objects be in invalid state and be specific about it. This goes to the other end of consistency scale from immutability as an object with multiple nullable fields has many invalid states.

Sample code:

```
namespace Temp.Models
{
    public class CurrentClass
    {
        public double? FirstCoefficient { get; set; }
        public double? SecondCoefficient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now this gets instantiated quite nicely and can be changed on the fly:

```
public CurrentClass CreateCurrentClass()
{
    var currentClass = new CurrentClass { FirstCoefficient = 1.0 };
    var secondCoefficient = RetrieveSecondCoefficient();
    currentClass.SecondCoefficient = secondCoefficient;

    return currentClass;
}
```

You'll however need validity checks everywhere the object is used.

```
public bool IsValid(CurrentClass currentClass)
{
    // what if FirstCoefficient has value and SecondCoefficient doesn't,
    // is that always an invalid state?
    return currentClass.FirstCoefficient.HasValue
        && currentClass.SecondCoefficient.HasValue;
}
```

Summary:

- Very little code is needed to have a DTO up and running
- A lot of consistency checks (and related brain pain) are required to work with such model
- Encapsulation is lacking - any method taking `CurrentClass` can alter its validity, therefore making the previous point even worse. This can be eased by usage of read-only interface passed where read-only access is required.

### Summing up

There are many other means that usually lay in between the two aforementioned approaches. For example you can use one validity flag (SergeyS's response) per object and ease on the external validity checks but having more code in the class and the need of deeper thinking.

Personally, I prefer immutability. It's more monkey code to write but will definitely pay off down the road thanks to the clean design.

A complex system without immutability is very hard to reason about without extensive knowledge. This is especially painful when working in a team - usually each person only knows a part of the codebase.

The sad thing is that it's not always possible to have evertything immutable (e.g. viewmodels): then I tend to convert objects to an internal immutable model as soon as it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth analysis! This is great help!

Answer (score 0):

Given what you already wrote, I would add `Initialize()` method and `Initialized` property into your `MainClass` class. Something similar to this:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private CurrentClass _currentClass = new CurrentClass();

    public CurrentClass CurrentClass
    {
        get { return _currentClass; }
        set { _currentClass = value; }
    }

    public bool Initialized {get; private set;}

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.CurrentClass.FirstCoefficient = 0;
        this.CurrentClass.SecondCoefficient = 5;

        this.Initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Call `Initialize()` method where your conditions met.
Later in code you can just check `if(currentObject.Initialized)`. Notice private setter for `Initialized' property, it will ensure this flag was not accidentally set by external code.

Depending on your needs, you can go further and pass parameters for initialization directly to `Initialize()` method as parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this would work, there is a lot of solutions. So I will explore them and see which would be the best approach before choosing a correct answer. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You have several approaches, like force values to be correct in constructor or have another variable telling if object has no value yet, like System.Drawing.Point has static "Empty" property. But in this case of your simple object your main class is explicitly creating an instance of CurrentClass so at this point this object should be correct and coefficients should be set. If you rely on some other code to set those values to perform some other action later, it is out of scope of these two objects here.

Update: perharps sharing details of what the real problem is would be better, because I have a feeling trying to provide a simpified example ended up in hiding real problem.

Comment: the real problem is that I am reading all of this information from a file being sent in. If this file has the data then I input the information as needed (define the variables already initialized).

Comment: In this case I would create an object (main class) only if data came in successfully, having null instead, or exception generated if data was not available.